# Embed mini player like bandcamp on facebook

Tags: facebook

I am in the situation, where I want my share link to be converted into a mini player to let users play the music directly just like what bandcamp does.

I have been pulling my hairs in putting the same feature for my client's website. But no luck till now.

I just want to know whether it is possible for us or not. I mean this feature is probably only for bandcamp or soundclound sites ?

My link is converting the object into video tag and the bandcamp link is getting converted into iframe.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Embedding custom HTML5 content onto timelines via iframe is only possible for a limited set of Facebook partners as of now. You can only embed a flash player as a “video”, and have that play your audio tracks.

Comment: Will jplayer go for that or jwplayer ?